# C statement to ask for system password when opening a file in ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, file, permissions

if I have a client descriptor as follows:

```
int fileDescriptor = open("myfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

how can I edit this statement so that, if I want to open it (double click) I will be asked for the system password?

Comment: Open it in what?

Comment: Double clicking its icon on my desktop, for example or gedit or cat

Comment: That's a lot of work!